# How do i manually place a widget code

Tags: widgets

Is there a way that i can place a certain widget anywhere on the site?

**For example**:

I'm using the text widget in my sidebar, for the title I put YouTube, and I placed the YouTube embed code in it.
But I want that widget to go at the top of the site. How do I make this possible, while still using the widgets menu, but not show up in the sidebar, but wherever I place it?

If it's not possible, does anyone know of a YouTube sidebar widget, one that can let you place the widget code anywhere on the site and also do it from the widgets menu?

Comment: you need to create a custom widget area in your theme , and then in the widgets menu assign the widget to that area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just register another widget area. Don’t take the name *sidebar* literally, you can use the fields anywhere on your page.

In your theme’s `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_multiple_widget_areas' );

function register_multiple_widget_areas()
{
    register_sidebar(
        array(
        'name'          => 'Sidebar',
        'id'            => 'sidebar',
        'description'   => 'describe the function of the box.'
        )
    );
    register_sidebar(
        array(
        'name'          => 'Header',
        'id'            => 'header-widget',
        'description'   => 'Goes at the top of the page.'
        )
    );
}
```

And wherever you need the header widget call:

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'header-widget' );
```

See also [`register_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) and [`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget):

```
the_widget(
    'WP_Widget_Archives',
    [
        'title'    => __( 'Archives', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'count'    => true,
        'dropdown' => true,
    ],
    [
        'before_widget' => '<section class="widget__container">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget__title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ]
);
```

Comment: and add what to it, the title of the text widget?

Comment: I guess you need to re-write your Q. I'm not quite sure if I understand.

Comment: details. arguments.